# pass input value from activities c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to pass user input text from activity1 to activity2.
I tried alot of thing but all of the thing did to me this error,
this is the error i get when i'm trying to put the value in textview.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cpsbflk4r1ep46x/error.PNG

```
//this is the first activity 

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        TextView t1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.t1);

        long l = 1;

        ImageButton i1 = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.i1);

        i1.Click += delegate
        {

            t1.Text = l++.ToString();
        };

        Button b1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.b1);
        b1.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            string b = t1.Text;
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity2));
            intent.PutExtra("j", b);
            StartActivity(intent);
        };

//this is the second activity

        TextView money = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.money);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
        var l = this.Intent.Extras.GetString("j");

        money.Text = l;
```

thanks,

Comment: Please post complete exception text here. (including line number of your exception)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/les85bh06dwvkax/error2.PNG

Comment: please, show output when exception raised

Comment: I sent a photo this is the output that I get

Comment: I really need help so if someone have an idea it will be awsome

Answer (score 0):

You can get your string by using the method `getStringExtra(QUERY)`:

```
var l = Intent.getStringExtra("j");
```

If you ever get a null and you're using `getStringExtra(QUERY)`. Add a `.toString()` to your variable which is used in the PutExtra. In your case this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Ahh nvm, I'll delete my Edit. That's Android only, Xamarin has the property Text, so you're doing that right.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

On the main activity

```
var activity2 = new Intent (this, typeof(next_activity));
                activity2.PutExtra ("value",i);
                StartActivity (activity2);
```

On the next_activity

```
  var Passed_value  = Intent.GetStringExtra ("value",0);
    // for int use: Intent.GetIntExtra
```

Also try changing

```
t1.Text = l++.ToString();
```

to

```
t1.Text = l++;
```

and

```
string b = t1.Text;
```

to

```
string b = t1.Text.ToString();
```