# android c# xamarin. How to display associated table in listview?

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, listview, xamarin

I have sqlite database in Asset folder. I displayed one of the table in the listview (code below), but I have a problem with displaying another table, related to the first one, after clicking row in the list view. i.e. table has data about the competitions and each competition have a associated table with number of fixtures. After clicking a competition row I like to display fixtures associated witch this competition.
How can I do that?
Thank you all

```
using (var contents = con.CreateCommand())
               {

                   contents.CommandText = "SELECT * from Competition";
                   var r = contents.ExecuteReader();
                   while (r.Read())
                       items.Add(string.Format("\n\t{0}", r["name"].ToString()));


                   con.Close();

                   ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
               }}

            protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
                    {
                       var t = items[position];
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. I changed my query:

```
 using (var contents = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            contents.CommandText = "SELECT [_id], [name], [shortName],[defaultCompetitionRule_id] from [Competition]";
            var r = contents.ExecuteReader();
            while (r.Read())
            {
                tl.Add(FromReader(r));
            }
            con.Close();
            ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, tl.Select(x => x.name).ToArray());
        }
```

My FromReader():

```
Competition FromReader(SqliteDataReader r)
    {
        var t = new Competition();
        t._id = Convert.ToInt32(r["_id"]);
        t.name = r["name"].ToString();
        t.shortName = r["shortName"].ToString();
        t.defaultCompetitionRule_id = Convert.ToInt32(r["defaultCompetitionRule_id"]);
        return t;
     }
```

And OnListItemClick I got "id" of the clicked Competition and I sent it to the next activity:

```
 protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        var ids = tl.Select(x => x._id).ToArray();
        var t = ids[position];
        var activity2 = new Intent(this, typeof(SelectFixture));
        activity2.PutExtra("value", t.ToString());
        StartActivity(activity2);

    }
```

And Finally on the second activity I got the id:

```
Passed_value = Intent.GetStringExtra("value");
```

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

why not sending theposition to another fragment or activity and in this activity to display another listadapter?

Comment: Could you tell me how to send the position to another activity. I am new in c# and android.

Comment: Try with this:


On the main activity

var activity2 = new Intent (this, typeof(next_activity));
                activity2.PutExtra ("value",i);
                StartActivity (activity2);  
On the next_activity

  var Passed_value  = Intent.GetStringExtra ("value",0);
    // for int use: Intent.GetIntExtra
check also my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052577/pass-input-value-from-activities-c-sharp/25062990#25062990

Comment: Yes the sending works fine Thanks but I think insted of position I should send "id" of the clicked Competition that I can find fixtures associated with it. Please correct me if i'm wrong and I am not sure how to do that?